# What is a proper Learning Technique for the given data sample

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, fuzzy-logic, supervised-learning

I am working in matlab.

I have data samples of **two unrelated** variables at `256` time-steps. Their plots with their value on Y - axis and time-steps on X-axis is as below.
Typical Plot for the first variable say `Pos` is [image]

Typical Plot for the second variable say `Vel` is [image]

Now I need to predict the values for these variables at next `10` time-steps. To check various machine learning techniques to do so , I took values  of the variables at first `246` time-steps , predicted the next `10` time-steps and then compared them  with their actual value by calculating the mean square error say `ms_error`.

I have done this using `time-series(NAR) ,linear regression,fuzzy input systems,neural networks`. but none of these are able to give the value of `ms_error` lesser than 2.
Can someone suggest a learning algorithm to use to predict future values for data samples like these two.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with symbolic regression via Genetic Programming.

[Genetic Programing](http://www.gp-field-guide.org.uk/) makes no assumption about the structure of the function that fits your data points, so it's well suited to this sort of discovery task.

[Symbolic regression](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/poli/gp-field-guide/122CurveFittingDataModellingandSymbolicRegression.html) was one of the earliest applications of GP and continues to be [widely studied](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22genetic+programming%22+%22symbolic+regression%22&btnG=&hl=it&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1).

There are many ready-to-use environments for every major programming language and many tutorials on the subject e.g.

- C++: [Beagle](http://code.google.com/p/beagle/)
- Java: [ECJ](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/)
- Matlab: [GPTIPS](https://sites.google.com/site/gptips4matlab/) - [GPLAB](http://gplab.sourceforge.net/)
- Python: [DEAP](http://deap.gel.ulaval.ca/doc/0.7/examples/symbreg.html)

(I don't mean these are the best, just well known. Of course Google search could bring up other software that is more suitable for your needs).

Comment: I know this may sound as a real amateur , but Google search has really not given me any satisfactory answers. Maybe I am not using the correct keywords. Anyways,I am checking out your suggestions now.